# Passing in Variables as Pointers, References, Constant References, Etcetera: What Happens at the Hardware Level?

Tags: c++, pointers

I would like to understand what actually happens when using different methods of passing in a variable to a function. Please critique my understanding and disabuse me where necessary.

The #1 thing I understand is that *"passing in a variable"* is just an expression. A function is a block of code stored at some memory location, and calling a function is calling the execution of that block of code. All that stuff about *"passing in a variable"* and *"returning a variable"* is just an abstraction for beginners to programming.

Most high-level languages only have pass-by-value for functions. (However, there are hacks to get pass-by-reference behavior, and in any event a compiler does whatever the Hell it wants, so you can't assume you know what's going to happen.)

C++ is kind of a mix of a low-level and high-level language. It's like a high-level language where you can override high-level behavior whenever you want to.

This is how pass-by-value works:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

is the same as

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    // ---- this is the function executing -----
    int temp = a;
    std::cout << temp;
    // -----------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

This is how pass-by-reference works:

```
void foo(int& a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

is the same as

```
void foo(int& a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    // ---- this is the function executing -----
    std::cout << a;
    // -----------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

This is how pass-by-pointer works:

```
void foo(int* a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    foo(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

is the same as

```
void foo(int* a)
{
    std::cout << *a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    // ---- this is the function executing -----
    int* temp = &a;
    std::cout << *temp;
    // -----------------------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, that's the same thing as passing by value, except the value is a pointer.

Now, what about the `const &` parameter that is seen all the time in C++? What does that do exactly? Well, it's nothing special.

```
void foo(const int& a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

works the exact same as

```
void foo(int& a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

The `const` is just an agreement between you and the compiler, that you won't change the value of `a` in the execution of the function.

What if you pass a reference to a pointer?

```
void foo(int*& a)
{
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

is the same as

```
void foo(int& a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}
```

except more inefficient because you have to dereference.

Am I right about all that????

Answer (score 1):

The hardware knows only about addresses. Read wikipages on [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture), [instruction set architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), [addressing mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode), [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM), [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit), [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)

At the hardware level, references, pointers, addresses are all the same.

Of course, you need an [optimizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler).  Learn more about [application binary interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (read the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) spec) and [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (notably [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)).

If using GCC, I would suggest to compile with `g++ -Wall -S -O2 -fverbose-asm` then look at the generated assembly code.

Read Drepper's paper: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf%E2%80%8E).

Answer (score 1):

- All function arguments/result values are passed by their representation (a value (integral/floating point), a pointer or a reference (leaving conversions aside))
- Any representation can be passed to CPU registers directly
- A pointer and a reference are essentially the same, both reflect a memory address, where the pointer can be modified to point to a different address and the reference can be modified (due to C++ functionality) to hold a different value at the address it is pointing to (again: leaving conversions aside).

(I hope this is helpful)

Comment: It is important to note that a pointer and a reference may not be handled the same way by the hardware.  Compilers are allowed to optimize away references if they deem they can. Though when passing references to functions, I believe in most cases and implementations the transfer is handled much like a pointer - but I don't believe it has to be.